# Angular object undefined

Tags: angular, object

In my angular project, I have the following:

**TS**

```
this.storage.get(item_section).then((value) => {
    this.item= value;
    console.log(this.item); //The console log gives `["name","item","size"]`
    console.log(this.item[1]); //Gives `item` as the console log
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="something">{{item}}</div> //Displays "name,item,size"
<div class="something">{{item[1]}}</div> //Gets Undefined error
```

If I can define the `this.item` and get results for `{{item}}`, how come I get undefined error for `{{item[1]}}`?

I am little confused to how to fix this

Comment: Your code asynchronous. Just think about it

Comment: `item` is only assignable when the async operation finishes. You can use something like this in component: `this.item = this.storage.get(item_section);` and in template: `<ng-container *ngIf="item | async as resolvedItem"><div class="something">{{resolvedItem[1]}}</div></ng-container>`

Comment: If you want to know why it happens, you can see [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron#23667087).

Comment: @developer033 Thank you! I was looking through some forums to see why it was the case. Much appreciated guys!=)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your operation is async, so you need to wait for the **item** to be loaded to access the second element of the **item**. You can use *ngIf to achieve it.

```
<div class="something" *ngIf="item">{{item[1]}}</div>
```

Comment: *"...to be loaded to access the first element..."* In fact, he doesn't want to access the **first** element, but the second :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply add a '?' next to your array item, it should work fine. Refer Safe Navigation Operator for displaying data if exists.

Comment: It's called `Safe Navigation Operator`.

Comment: Hmm, I just remembered that the `Safe Navigation Operator` doesn't support this kind of situation (I mean bracket notation)... if you try: `item?[1]` you'll get a "Template parse errors...".

Comment: Yes, I just checked it out myself. It throws a template parse error.

Comment: @developer033 I think a ternary operator would work just fine in this case :) `item[1]?item[1]:''`

Comment: No, it won't work also, it still produces error, you can do: `{{ item ? item[1] : '' }}`.

Comment: I tried implementing both of our approaches and both of them are working :)

Comment: The original problem in question is that `item` is **undefined**, so the last approach that you suggested (`item[1]?item[1]:''`)  won't work because you're trying to access [1] from undefined... actually you're trying to do something like this: `undefined[1] ? undefined[1] : ''`.

Comment: I understand your predicament and what you are conveying makes sense. But I am still trying to figure out why that actually worked :P What I did was assign a variable : `public sample: string[]` and put up a binding in the DOM like `{{sample[0]?:sample[0]:''}}` and it isn't producing any error while compiling.

Answer (score 1):

It should work for the static data, it works fine here.

Check the **[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/HejMUtURWEkpWkghFFpS?p=preview)**

Alternatively since your code is asynchronous, you can try this,

```
<div class="something">{{item && item[0]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

please try below:

```
<div class="something" *ngFor="let itm of item | async">{{itm}}</div>
```